# Only background is there, no icons, blank screen

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, login, screen

I am using dual boot in my pc with win10 and Ubuntu 14, 
Until now everything was working fine... Suddenly today when I tried to login to Ubuntu,
 login screen came as normal but strangely after login no icons or anything is displayed, only desktop background and cursor was present..
Someone help me out here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably unity plugin is disabled. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type **ccsm**, accept with enter. Find and click on ubuntu unity plugin and (if not) check it.

If you haven't got **ccsm**, install it :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Comment: ctrl+alt+t  is also not working... But tried ctrl+alt+f1 and installed ccsm ,but ccsm is not opening...

Comment: after ctrl+alt+f1 try this command to reset compiz : sudo DISPLAY=:0  dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, As u told I tried  "compiz : sudo DISPLAY=:0 dconf reset -f /org/compiz/" the result was "compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core"  "compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core" "compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display" "compiz (core) - Info: Stopping plugin: core" " compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: core"

Comment: sudo DISPLAY=:0 dconf reset -f /org/compiz - if this is not working try removing configuration with : rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*

Comment: I did this :  the   ~ sign said invalid option so i tried this "rm -rf /.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*" there was  no reply and then I tried to reboot.. nothing new happened, same problem persists... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try reinstalling ubuntu desktop : sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop and then sudo apt-get install unity

Comment: Rebooted and still the problem persists

Comment: Try this ctrl+alt+f1 and launch ccsm like this : DISPLAY=:0 ccsm, than press alt+f7, ccsm should launch and you should be able to find ubuntu unity plugin and see if it is checked

Comment: if not you can try : ctrl+alt+f1 ant than: export DISPLAY=:0 sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz and than setsid unity

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get an opportunity to try ur command , I did a backup of programs by using," $ sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack fakeroot
$ mkdir ~/dpkg-repack; cd ~/dpkg-repack
$ fakeroot -u dpkg-repack `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f1` " and copied the folder to another drive by booting into try mode from boot CD, and then I reinstalled ubuntu freshly , I think the problem came after I installed some new programs like motif , thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 0):

Found a perfect solution for this problem : had the same prob in friends lap , used the following commands alt+ctrl+f2 , in terminal 
"sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^"

This installed all the missing application like unity and gnome, etc, . I didn't have to completely reinstall Ubuntu for this problem.